# NHibernate Native SQL and DialectScope

Tags: .net, nhibernate

I have two native SQL queries. One for Oracle and one for MSSql. I want to run them trough NHibernate. How do I find out what Db-engine I'm on? I know I can add dialect-scope in mapping files for `<database-object />`. Is there something similar for `<sql-query />`? Or should I put an if-loop in my code and try to figure out the dialect?

Thanks.

Comment: Just to check: what is your native SQL query doing?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the version of the database. For Oracle that would be `SELECT * FROM V$VERSION` and for MSSql I could use `@@VERSION`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was never going to work: I need to parse the result differently according to the version of the database. An if-else on the dialect is the way to go here.

One other option would have been a Stored Procedure. Then I could use `database-object` and create one for each database. But I don't like stored procedures :)

Answer (score 1):

You can cast your NHibernate.ISessionFactory to a NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl and query its Dialect property, which is an object of a class derived from NHibernate.Dialect.Dialect (such as MsSql2000Dialect or Oracle8iDialect).

Subsequent versions of a database (2000, 2005, 2008) are implemented by classes derived from the previous version (use the Object Browser to analyse NHibernate.dll)

Answer (score 0):

If the SQL is the same for both queries, you can use the ADO.NET interfaces from an ISession. For example:

```
IDbConnection cxn = session.Connection;
using (IDbCommand cmd = cxn.CreateCommand)
{
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from schema.table";
    IDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader;
}
```

You can add parameters using `cmd.CreateParameter`.